# How to change HTTP Request Path for multiple HTTP Requests at once in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I have created JMeter HTTP request sampler project using Blazemeter recorder which created Jmx.file I have opened the same in JMeter to modify and fix the errors.

I have more than 100 HTTP requests with Name as 
https://abc.abc.com/AutoSave/PostSavedData

with Path value as `AutoSave/PostSavedData`

if I change the Path value to `PostSavedData` then this HTTP request show as Pass.

How do I change all HTTP requests path to PostSavedData without manually changing path for each HTTP Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Search) write what you want to replace in `Search:`

and replacement in `Replace by:`

and click `Replace All`

[image]

This is part of JMeter 5 [changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> Search feature has been improved to allow you to iterate in the tree over search results and do necessary replacements through Next/Previous/Replace/Replace/Find buttons

Answer (score 0):

Open the .JMX file in Notepad++ and replace "AutoSave/PostSavedData" with "PostSavedData". :)

Comment: This method works if there is no option on UI to search and replace. Enjoy load testing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From Jmeter 5 onwards you can press 'Cntrl + F' and then just replace the older string with the new one. Happy Load testing !!